# ngIf for closing/opening tag

Tags: html, angular, typescript, single-page-application

I have a table and I'm iterating in a  over an array. In some scenarios, I'll want to add an extra  `<tr>`. I'm looking for something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let element in array">
    <td>
      some content
    </td>
  //Starting block that will only be activated if some variable is true
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 
        some extra content
      </td>
 //End of the block that will only be activated if some variable is true
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way to create a boulder html that can wrap it like this?

The options I've tried so far are changing the data structure (array) so it include the element I'm looking for but I'm not pleased with having extra data there just for displaying purpose.

Comment: `*ngIf` is not an iterator, you need to use `*ngFor` instead.

Comment: It was a typo. It is a *ngFor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
<table>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let element in array"
    <tr>
      <td>
        some content
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="someVar">
      <td> 
        some extra content
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you could make it work :)

Answer (score -4):

Perhaps the best option is to work with [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Example with ng-repeat:

```
<table ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
        <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{x.Country}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Ng-repeat makes a for in your object or array.

See if this can help you.

Comment: There is no `ng-repeat` in Angular2.

Comment: ng-repeat is angularjs == angular 1 so it doesn't apply to my problem

Comment: Sorry, I did not see it was from Angular 2